# Difference between Apache Spark's Mllib-LinearSVC and Sklearn's LinearSVC

Tags: python-3.x, scala, scikit-learn, apache-spark-mllib

I am working on a `multi-class` text classification problem for which I have implemented my model using sklearn `LinearSVC` library in python with `loss = 'hinge'` and other parameters as default and it is giving satisfactory results for now.

Steps performed before passing the data:

1. Special character removal.
2. Stopwords removal.
3. Stemming.

Code part:

```
vectorizerPipe = Pipeline([('tfidf', TfidfVectorizer(lowercase=True,
        stop_words='english')),
('classification', OneVsRestClassifier(LinearSVC(penalty='l2', loss='hinge'))),])
```

Now, I want to implement the same in Spark using MLlib in scala. I am done with training and testing part. But, the results are mostly different.

```
val classifier = new LinearSVC()
  .setMaxIter(1000)
  .setRegParam(0.01)
  .setThreshold(0.5)
  .setTol(1E-4)

val ovr = new OneVsRest().setClassifier(classifier)

val pipeline = new Pipeline()
      .setStages(Array(tokenizer, stopword_removal, stemming, hashingTF, idf, indexer, ovr))
```

Comparatively, python is giving more correct results.

I used the below article to understand the basic difference between both the libraries and applied the same. But there is not much difference in results.

[should-mllib-linearsvc-behave-the-same-way-as-scik](https://forums.databricks.com/questions/11762/should-mllib-linearsvc-behave-the-same-way-as-scik.html)

Note: I am using spark 2.2.0 and `Linear SVC` under `OneVsRest Classifier`

Structure of Data:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| product_title          | Key_value_pairs                               | taxonomy_id (Output) |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Samsung S7 Edge        | Color:black,Display Size:5.5 inch,Internal    | 211 
                          Storage:128 GB, RAM:4 GB,Primary Camera:12 MP  

  Case cover Honor 8     | Color:transparent,Height:15 mm,width:22 mm    | 212 

  Ruggers Men's T-Shirt  | Size:L,ideal for:men,fit:regular,             | 111
                          sleeve:half sleeve

  Optimum Nutrition Gold | Flavor:chocolate,form:powder,size:34 gm       | 311
  Standard Whey Protein
```

I want to understand the basic difference between the two libraries and also which parameters need to be changed in MlLib's LinearSVC to get similar results.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Your sparkml pipeline is performing `stemming` which is not done by default in scikit TfidfVectorizer.

Comment: All the steps performed in Spark's pipeline are also performed in python as well. I have done that part before passing the data to the pipeline in python. Let me edit the question and add that details also.